# getting issue when trying to send diameter message out from the mobicents

Tags: mobicents

I am getting issue when trying to send diameter message out from the mobicents

```
2016-05-18 01:34:31,933 ERROR [org.mobicents.diameter.stack.DiameterStackMultiplexer] (Mobicents-SIP-Servlets-UDPMessageChannelThread-0) 
org.jdiameter.api.RouteException: Unable to find valid connection to peer[aaa://172.24.50.76:3868] in realm[open-ims.test]
    at org.jdiameter.client.impl.router.RouterImpl.getPeer(RouterImpl.java:389)
    at org.jdiameter.client.impl.controller.PeerTableImpl.sendMessage(PeerTableImpl.java:178)
    at org.jdiameter.client.impl.StackImpl.sendMessage(StackImpl.java:428)
    at org.jdiameter.client.impl.BaseSessionImpl.genericSend(BaseSessionImpl.java:121)
    at org.jdiameter.client.impl.BaseSessionImpl.genericSend(BaseSessionImpl.java:88)
    at org.jdiameter.client.impl.BaseSessionImpl$MyFuture.send(BaseSessionImpl.java:257)
    at org.jdiameter.client.impl.BaseSessionImpl.send(BaseSessionImpl.java:144)
    at org.mobicents.diameter.stack.DiameterStackMultiplexer.sendMessageSync(DiameterStackMultiplexer.java:322)
    at com.radisys.servlet.sip.DiameterClient.sendMessageSync(DiameterClient.java:230)
    at com.radisys.servlet.sip.DiameterClient.initializeExample(DiameterClient.java:130)
    at com.radisys.servlet.sip.DiameterClient.<init>(DiameterClient.java:91)
    at com.radisys.servlet.sip.Registration.doRegister(Registration.java:263)
    at javax.servlet.sip.SipServlet.doRequest(SipServlet.java:235)
    at javax.servlet.sip.SipServlet.service(SipServlet.java:325)
    at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.dispatchers.MessageDispatcher.callServlet(MessageDispatcher.java:235)
    at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.dispatchers.InitialRequestDispatcher$InitialDispatchTask.dispatch(InitialRequestDispatcher.java:727)
    at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.dispatchers.DispatchTask.dispatchAndHandleExceptions(DispatchTask.java:55)
    at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.dispatchers.InitialRequestDispatcher.dispatchInsideContainer(InitialRequestDispatcher.java:434)
    at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.dispatchers.InitialRequestDispatcher.dispatchMessage(InitialRequestDispatcher.java:298)
    at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.SipApplicationDispatcherImpl.processRequest(SipApplicationDispatcherImpl.java:701)
    at gov.nist.javax.sip.EventScanner.deliverEvent(EventScanner.java:230)
    at gov.nist.javax.sip.SipProviderImpl.handleEvent(SipProviderImpl.java:196)
    at gov.nist.javax.sip.DialogFilter.processRequest(DialogFilter.java:1303)
    at gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPServerTransaction.processRequest(SIPServerTransaction.java:847)
    at gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.UDPMessageChannel.processMessage(UDPMessageChannel.java:540)
    at gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.UDPMessageChannel.processIncomingDataPacket(UDPMessageChannel.java:492)
    at gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.UDPMessageChannel.run(UDPMessageChannel.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: `Unable to find valid connection to peer[aaa://172.24.50.76:3868]` , check the configuration for proper connection settings.